# Openiddict with microsoft as external provider throws missing client_id on calling callback

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, openiddict

I have written an auth service using OpenIddict. It should be possible to generate tokens for local accounts and microsoft accounts.

Authorizing on azure was succesfull but on redirecting to callback an invalid_client error is throwing by openiddict. -> error:invalid_client

it is configured as follows

startup.cs

```
// Register the OpenIddict server components.
                  .AddServer(options =>
                  {
                      options
                        //.AllowClientCredentialsFlow()
                        .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                         .RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
                        .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()//.AllowImplicitFlow()
                        .AllowPasswordFlow();


                      options
                    .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                    .SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                    .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/connect/introspect");


                      options.AddEncryptionCertificate(config["Certificates:EncryptionCertificate"]);

                      // Register the signing credentials.
                      options.AddSigningCertificate(config["Certificates:SigningCertificate"]);


                      // Register scopes (permissions)
                      options.RegisterScopes("api");

                      options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
                      options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));


                      // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core-specific options.
                      options
                    .UseAspNetCore()
                    .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                    .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough();


                  })
                  .AddClient(options=> 
                  {
                      options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate();
                      options.AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
                      options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();
                      options.UseAspNetCore().EnableRedirectionEndpointPassthrough();
                      options.UseWebProviders()
                      .AddMicrosoft(options=> {
                          options.SetClientId("xxxxx");
                          options.SetClientSecret("xxxx");
                          options.SetRedirectUri("connect/callback/microsoft");
                          
                      });
                  });
```

challenge in AccountController

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null, string provider="")
        {
            if (string.Equals(provider,"microsoft", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
 
                return new ChallengeResult(properties: null, authenticationSchemes: new[] { Providers.Microsoft });
        }
       }
```

callback is defined in AutorizationController

```
[HttpGet("~/callback/github")]
        [HttpPost("~/callback/github")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CallBackGitHub(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
```

I don't see any possiblities to add a client id on azures app registrations page. So how can i pass a client id which i have granted in openiddict?
Or is it possible to prevent checking client_id on executing callback function?